# Laravel get only users which they have specific Role using RelationShip

Tags: php, laravel

In my `Laravel` implemented web application i have `Users` and `Roles` tables with models which they are `ManyToMany`.

i want to get all users which they have specific role, for example:

```
$users = User::with(['roles' => function ($query) {
    $query->whereLabel('is-portal-manager');
}])->get();
```

unfortunately this code return all users and compare `role` label and return that in relation ship array

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#2069 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => App\User {#2076 ▼
      ...
      #relations: array:4 [▼
        "properties" => null
        "child" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#2073 ▶}
        "parent" => null
        "roles" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#2087 ▼
          #items: array:1 [▼
            0 => App\Entities\Role {#2074 ▼
              ...
              #attributes: array:5 [▼
                "id" => 1
                ...
                "label" => "is-portal-manager"
                ...
              ]
              ...
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
      ...
    }
    1 => App\User {#2077 ▼
      ...
      #relations: array:4 [▼
        "roles" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#2093 ▼
          #items: []
        }
      ]
      ...
    }
  ]
}
```

as you can see in above output second user doesn't have any role and `#items: []` is empty. i don't need to have this output structure and i want to have only which users have specific `role`, not all users with `empty` roles. second item of this collection shouldn't this output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your relationship conditional by using Laravel's `whereHas`:

```
$users = User::whereHas('roles', function ($query) {
    $query->whereLabel('is-portal-manager');
})->with('roles')->get();
```

Official documentations for further reading on Eloquent [Relationship Existence methods](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) **whereHas**, **has**, **doesntHave** and **whereDoesntHave**